# Is it possible to label a price on the y-axis?

Tags: pine-script

When viewing a stock, there are marked prices on the y-axis such as Last Price.

I am aware of how to create a label on a bar, but is it possible to create a label that will highlight the price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Chart Settings** -> **Scales** -> check **Indicator Last Value Label**. A label will appear on the y-axis, with name and color equal to the ones provided as argument in `plot`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: doesnt work from me.  my indicator draws a horizontal line but label doesnt appear on axis even when i have that check box ticked